# How can I store async task in a dictionary and call them according to config value?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

Here is my code below:

```
public interface IResponseEntity
{
}

public class ResponseEntity : IResponseEntity
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectForRequest
{
    public string abcd { get; set; }
    public string xyz { get; set; }
    public string pqrs { get; set; }
    public short mnop { get; set; }
}

private async Task<IResponseEntity> Dowork_for_A(ObjectForRequest objReq)
{
    //Code for A
    ....................
}

private async Task<IResponseEntity> Dowork_for_B(ObjectForRequest objReq)
{
    //Code for B
    ....................
}

private async Task<IResponseEntity> Dowork_for_C(ObjectForRequest objReq)
{
    //Code for C
    ....................
}

private async Task<IResponseEntity> Dowork_for_D(ObjectForRequest objReq)
{
    //Code for D
    ....................
}

public async Task<IResponseEntity> method(ObjectForRequest objReq)
{
    if (CONFIGVALUE == 'A')
        return await Dowork_for_A(RequestOBJ);
    else if (CONFIGVALUE == 'B')
        return await Dowork_for_B(RequestOBJ);
    else if (CONFIGVALUE == 'C')
        return await Dowork_for_C(RequestOBJ);
    else if (CONFIGVALUE == 'D')
        return await Dowork_for_D(RequestOBJ);
    else
        return null;
}
```

As if now I am checking config value in the if condition and then calling async task to return value.

How can I setup `<key, value>` pair of dictionary as config value as 'key' and  'value'  as async task? Or in other words here how can I store async task in a dictionary and call them according to config value?

Comment: Not my specialty, but isn’t this what Actions are for?

Comment: Could you show an example of how you envision using the `Dictionary` containing the `Task`s?

Comment: I think you have a typo in `method` - `RequestOBJ` should be `objReq` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very straightforward. Declare your dictionary as such:

```
    Dictionary<char, Func<ObjectForRequest, Task<IResponseEntity>>> _actions =
         new Dictionary<char, Func<ObjectForRequest, Task<IResponseEntity>>>()
    {
        { 'A', Dowork_for_A },
        { 'B', Dowork_for_B }
        // ...
    }
```

Then:

```
public async Task<IResponseEntity> method(ObjectForRequest objReq)
{
     Func<ObjectForRequest, Task<IResponseEntity>> action;
     if (!_actions.TryGetValue(CONFIGVALUE, out action))
     {
          return null;
     }   
     return await action(objReq);
}
```

Also, please do consider the performance implications of this. Dictionary's are wicked fast for large sets, but if you really do only have 3 or 4 options, a `switch` or `if ... else` chain is almost certainly going to be faster. What the exact tipping point is when `Dictionary` becomes better is hard to say.

Comment: If there are only 3 or 4 options and you're starting up a task then the relative speed of using a dictionary or a switch, etc, is hardly going to be an issue.